# How to use a swift geocoder on a venue/business name to get address

Tags: swift, geocoding, cllocation, geocode

I am trying to get the address for a venue/business name. With the venue name I have the city and state as well, but it is successful less than 10% of the time. The problem seems to be with finding the location and not deciphering the address.

Example Input: "Jazz Kitchen Indianapolis,Indiana"

Typical Output: "No location found"

Thanks!

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(newSearch) { (placemarks, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Geocoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        geoError = true
                    }
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        if let address = placemark.location?.coordinate {
                            print("Address: \(address)")
                            let webLoc = CLLocation(latitude: address.latitude, longitude: address.longitude)
                            uploadLoc(geoLoc: webLoc)
                        } else {
                            print("No address found")
                            geoError = true
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No location found")
                        geoError = true
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Probably the wrong api altogether, I assume it looks for a street or place named “Jazz Kitchen”.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "Jazz Kitchen" is a place in that city. Enter that same search term in the Maps app and it works just fine.

Comment: @HangarRash I meant a place like a square, a bridge or some famous building, not a company/business and could it be that the Maps app uses other sources apart from this api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example request in your question, using `MKLocalSearch` works better than `CLGeocoder`.

The following code:

```swift
import MapKit

let req = MKLocalSearch.Request()
req.naturalLanguageQuery = "Jazz Kitchen Indianapolis,Indiana"
let srch = MKLocalSearch(request: req)
srch.start { resp, error in
    if let resp {
        print(resp.mapItems)
    } else if let error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}
```

gives the following result:

```
[<MKMapItem: 0x600002df8d00> {
    isCurrentLocation = 0;
    name = "The Jazz Kitchen";
    phoneNumber = "<redacted for SO>";
    placemark = "The Jazz Kitchen, 5377 N College Ave, Indianapolis, IN 46220, United States @ <+39.85087740,-86.14554230> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+39.85087741,-86.14554230> radius 141.17', center:<+39.85087741,-86.14554230>, radius:141.17m)";
    timeZone = "America/Indiana/Indianapolis (EST) offset -18000";
    url = "http://www.thejazzkitchen.com";
}]
```